# Build of my oat ++ project causes problems of non-reference to my methods

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I didn't create the project structure,is a Oat++ starter project,
My CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(project_name ServerRestCmd) ## rename your project here

project(${project_name})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library(${project_name}-lib
        src/AppComponent.hpp
        src/controller/MyController.cpp
        src/controller/MyController.hpp
        src/controller/phylayer.cpp
        src/controller/phylayer.hpp
        src/dto/DTOs.hpp
)
## link libs

find_package(oatpp 1.1.0 REQUIRED)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network SerialPort REQUIRED)
add_definitions(-fPIC)
include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Network_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5SerialPort_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${project_name}-lib
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp
        PUBLIC oatpp::oatpp-test
        Qt5::Core
        Qt5::Network
        Qt5::SerialPort
)

target_include_directories(${project_name}-lib PUBLIC src)

## add executables

add_executable(${project_name}-exe
        src/App.cpp
        test/app/MyApiTestClient.hpp)
target_link_libraries(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
add_dependencies(${project_name}-exe ${project_name}-lib)
```

[image]

I added the phylayer.cpp, phylayer.hpp files and the references to the core, network and Serial modules of the QT. (These seem ok). At build time I have the following errors

[image]

what's missing in CmakeLists.txt?

Comment: All "undefined reference" are about methods of `PhyLayer` class which seems to be defined by you. Without viewing this definition we simply cannot help you. And please, do NOT use **images** for show the text of the error messages. Instead, paste this **text** into the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: Of course they are defined by me, but they work in another project, only when I put them in there did they stop working. Ok next time better place, sorry I'm in a hurry